# Place the values of repeated fields in an array

Tags: python

I have a  file in this format,

```
dn: abvf
changetype: a
objectclass: in
objectclass: c
objectclass: cdsUser
objectclass: or
objectclass: Person
objectclass: nd
objectclass: Top
ACL :HH
ACL: JJJ
`
`
dn: abvf
changetype: a
objectclass: in
objectclass: c
objectclass: cdsUser
objectclass: or
objectclass: Person
objectclass: nd
objectclass: Top
ACL :HH
ACL: JJJ
```

how do you produce a file like this,

```
dn: abvf
changetype: a
objectclass: ['','','','']
ACL :['','']
`
`
dn: abvf
changetype: a
objectclass: ['','','','']
ACL :['','']
```

basically i want to parse this file and if it has same fields multiple times,
store its value in an array(with out hard coding), because i have many different entries like that with different repeating fields.

Is there a way to achieve this ,please help me out.

Comment: What is your intent by mentioning "without hard coding"? Does that mean there may be repeating tags other than 'objectclass' and 'ACL'? Or just that you don't know how many times the fields will occur

Comment: yes there are many such repeating fields other than 'objecclass' and 'ACL'

Comment: Parse each line, and store it in a dictionary. If you encounter any tag for the second time, it will be present in the list of keys while the value won't be a `list`. Then you can replace the single value in the dict with a list of values, and keep appending.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample of what I mentioned in the comment above. I've assumed a newline (`\n`) is what separates two different objects. You end up with a list of dicts, which you can then use to print/write as per your needs. Note that `pprint` is only for better printing, and you won't actual need that when writing to a file.

```
import pprint

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj_list = []
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
    with open('input.txt', 'r') as input_file:
        temp_dict = {}
        for line in input_file:
            if line == '\n':
                # empty dict evaluates to false
                if temp_dict:
                    obj_list.append(temp_dict)
                    temp_dict = {}
            else:
                k, v = line.strip().split(':')
                k, v = k.strip(), v.strip()

                if k in temp_dict.keys():
                    if not isinstance(temp_dict[k], list):
                        old_value_as_list = [temp_dict[k]]
                        temp_dict[k] = old_value_as_list
                    temp_dict[k].append(v)
                else:
                    temp_dict[k] = v

        # since file may not end with newline
        if temp_dict:
            obj_list.append(temp_dict)
            temp_dict = {}

        pp.pprint(obj_list)

        with open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
            for obj in obj_list:
                for k,v in obj.items():
                    output_file.write(f'{k}: {v}\n')
                output_file.write('\n')
```

Output:

```
[   {   'ACL': ['HH', 'JJJ'],
        'changetype': 'a',
        'dn': 'abvf',
        'objectclass': ['in', 'c', 'cdsUser', 'or', 'Person', 'nd', 'Top']},
    {   'ACL': ['HH', 'JJJ'],
        'changetype': 'a',
        'dn': 'abvf',
        'objectclass': ['in', 'c', 'cdsUser', 'or', 'Person', 'nd', 'Top']}]
```

Comment: how do you write that to a new file i the expected format above

Comment: You can easily find tutorials online on how to write to files using Python.

Comment: @MohanKumar I've added the code to write to file according to your question. Please mark the answer as accepted if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a dictionary for each block and use it to accumulate repeated values for each keyword:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as inFile:
    lines = inFile.read().split("\n")

with open('ouptput.txt','w') as outFile:
    block = dict()
    for line in lines+[""]:
        if line in ["`",""]:
            outLines = [f"{k}:{[v[0],v][len(v)>1]}" for k,v in block.items()]
            outFile.write("\n".join(outLines+[line])+"\n")
            block = dict()
            continue
        keyword,value = line.split(":",1)
        block.setdefault(keyword,list()).append(value.strip())
```